# Как получить через функции или содержимое файла его тип php

Tags: php, файлы

Нужно получить расширение файла имея сам файл, сразу расскажу суть, я понимаю что можно получить весь текст после последней точки, и в большинстве случаев это будет работать, но в windows через баг можно создать файл-приложение с расширением jpg суть в том что расширение .exe можно перемещать в имени то есть например есть файл .exe_myphoto.jpeg или иными способами. по сути система воспримет его как exe но простой explode выявит .jpeg в итоге запускаемый файл будет загружен, что естественно меня не радует

Comment: Используйте [finfo](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/class.finfo.php) и конечно же [Exif](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/ref.exif.php)

Comment: Вообще-то, файл '.exe_myphoto.jpeg' любая Windows воспримет исключительно как jpg.